# SQL query for the following output?

Tags: sql, mysql

Table `test` with columns `compname version`  and  table `Bugs` with columns `bugid compname`

Data for `test`:

`A 1.2`
`B 1.5`
`C 1.6`
`B 1.3`
`C 1.5`
`A 1.6`
`B 1.6`

Data for `Bugs`:

`1 A`
`1 C`
`2 A`
`2 B`
`3 A`
`3 B`
`3 C`

query is:

`Output the compname where version=1.6 and affected by bugid=1 along with the first(min) version in which the component appeared`

Output:
`A  1.2`
`C  1.5`

I am using this query, but can this be made faster:

`select compname,min(version) from test where compname IN (select compname from test where version='1.6' and compname IN (select compname from Bugs where bugid=1)) group by compname`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Joins are faster, and you'll need an extra self-join to get the min version.

```
SELECT t.compname, min(t2.version)
FROM test t
INNER JOIN Bugs b
  ON t.compname = b.compname
INNER JOIN test t2
  ON t.compname = t2.compname
WHERE bugid = 1 AND t.version='1.6'
GROUP BY t.compname
```

(In my test it gave the same results you listed)

Comment: Otherwise you'll only get the min of the rows retrieved, which are only the ones that match `bugid = 1 AND t.version='1.6'`.  This way you get all possible versions, and choose the min of that set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT test.compname, min(test.version) 
FROM test INNER JOIN Bugs
ON test.compname = Bugs.compname
WHERE test.version = '1.6' AND Bugs.bugid =1
GROUP BY test.compname
```

Comment: How is this different from @Jason or my answers?

Comment: @Abe - no aliasing and he reversed the order of the `WHERE` clause :)

Comment: @Abe - I only saw those answers after I posted... Apparently I'm a slower typer then you :)

Comment: The solution is incorrect. It will need two inner joins otherwise min version will always show as 1.6